# race condition in root variables in module?

Tags: go

Is it possible to experience race conditions when you use "root" variables in module?

Let's say you have a module called `db` and you import it many different files in your complied project

```
package db

var global_var map[string]string
```

Can you be sure that this variable is persistent to many concurrent reads and writes? In one file `db.global_var` is changed, then the new value is distributed to all the other files where the package `db` is imported?

How to implement a solution with atomic functionality?

Comment: *"Can you be sure ..."* -- reads-only yes, writes no. You should use a mutex if you want read and write the variable from multiple goroutines.

Comment: @mkopriva then how can you use "global" variables in go where you want to be able to update the value?

Comment: By using a mutex for example. See [`sync.Mutex`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync@go1.21.0#Mutex).

Comment: Or use `atomic.Value`, or a function that serialized access

Comment: To be clear the variable is accessible from all the modules at all times. But without some form of locking/atomic update you might see a partially updated value.

Comment: No values are ever safe for concurrent reads and writes, regardless of their scope.

Comment: Or `sync.Map`, if the usecase aligns with that. Point is, if you write a code that has a race, then it has a race. It doesn't matter whether the data is global or not. Globals don't provide any special guarantees that other variables don't. They just make it easy for everyone to poke their fingers in where they don't belong.

Comment: FYI, [a useful distinction](https://medium.com/@val_deleplace/does-the-race-detector-catch-all-data-races-1afed51d57fb) exists between a _synchronisation bug_ and a _race condition_. The latter is a manifestation of the former.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're a native English speaker or not, but that word "distributed" in «…the new value is distributed to all the other files where the package db is imported?» caught my attention: if that was a correctly picked word, you might have a wrong mental model about what constututes an import of a symbol in Go. First, a unit across boundaries of which imports happen, is a package, not file; source code files exist only until compilation phase is complete, and even at linking phase they do not exist anymore–let alone complete executable module.…

Comment: …Then, an imported symbol is not somehow _copied_ into different packages (or files constituting its source code, if you wish). In a compiled program loaded into computer memory each variable declared in Go source code exists only in a single place in memory (during the time it's "live", of course). Global variables exist during the whole program's run time, and each exist just in a single location in memory, physically. All the places in the code which use it–read or write–are made to "know" its location when the program is compiled and linked.…

Comment: …So basically the problem (in your case) is: what happens when several goroutines running on physically separate CPU cores (or CPUs) fully in parallel access that same single memory location at the same time instant, and at least one of these accesses is a write? Here, given the modern technology, things quickly get quite compilcated and may be surprising. A naive idea that all the accesses will be automagically _serialized_ is awfully wrong–for good or for bad, but wrong. You may start [here](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use map concurrently for read/write you have to use some sync. In other case, it will cause a race condition. Easiest way to achieve it - use sync.Mutex or sync.RWMutex (more efficient in case of concurrent read/write).

You can use [sync.Map](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) as an alternative also. But it can be slower since it's general-purpose nature. sync.Map uses `interface{}` (or [any](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#any) which is just an alias for `interface{}`) both for key and value of the map. So you will need to assert types ([type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) is not very fast operation).

Typical approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type SyncMap struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex
    m  map[string]string
}

func New() *SyncMap {
    return &SyncMap{
        m: make(map[string]string),
    }
}

func (sm *SyncMap) Set(key, val string) {
    sm.mu.Lock()
    defer sm.mu.Unlock() // or without defer in the end of method - will be faster
    sm.m[key] = val
}

func (sm *SyncMap) Get(key string) (val string, ok bool) {
    sm.mu.RLock()
    defer sm.mu.RUnlock() // or without defer in the end of method - will be faster
    val, ok = sm.m[key]
    return
}

func (sm *SyncMap) Delete(key string) {
    delete(sm.m, key)
}

func main() {
    m := New()

    key := "Hello"
    val := ", World!"

    v, ok := m.Get(key)
    fmt.Printf("%s %s OK: %v\n", key, v, ok)

    m.Set(key, val)
    v, ok = m.Get(key)
    fmt.Printf("%s %s OK: %v\n", key, v, ok)

    m.Delete(key)
    v, ok = m.Get(key)
    fmt.Printf("%s %s OK: %v\n", key, v, ok)
}
```

But if you want to distribute variable value just in case of changes then, I think, it's better to use channels-based approach.

Comment: A "type assertion" is not a slow of fast operation, it is a static assertion of the type stored in an interface. Performance issues with [`sync.Map`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) are either because it is optimized for a different access pattern (as documented) or in some cases the slight overhead of the interface indirection.

Comment: Will this solution also work if the struct/object is located in a package? What if different gorotines writes to the "wrong" object?

Comment: - and if the package is imported in several files?

Comment: Yes, it will work. In you case package name will be 'db' and readers/writers should use only Set/Get/Delete. They cannot access directly to map in structure as it is private. I din't understand what means "wrong" object, but, of course, you should use the same variable of type SyncMap for all readers/writes. Initialise it somewhere once with New function. No matter how many files import the package.

Comment: About type assertion you are right: it's highly optimised, but still a little bit slower.

Comment: @EugeneMikhalev What do you mean by `or without defer in the end of method - will be faster` the comments?

Comment: technically `defer` has a small bit of overhead, but it's nothing to be concerned about, at least until you've optimized the big stuff after careful benchmarking.